# Compatibility of different exchange structures $\operatorname{Ex}^*_{\#},\operatorname{Ex}^*_*,\operatorname{Ex}_{\# *}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, triangulated-categories, motivic-homotopy, stable-homotopy-category

Let $\mathcal{Cat}$ denotes the $2$-category of small categories and $\mathscr{S}=\mathrm{Sch}/S$ be some category of schemes over a given scheme $S$, consider a $2$-functor $\mathscr{M}:\mathscr{S}^{op} \longrightarrow \mathcal{Cat}$.

For each morphism $f: X \longrightarrow Y$, we denote by $f^*:\mathscr{M}(Y) \longrightarrow \mathscr{M}(X)$ the corresponding fiber functor and suppose that:

- Each $f^*$ admits a right adjoint, denoted by $f_*:\mathscr{M}(X) \longrightarrow \mathscr{M}(Y)$.
- If $f$ is smooth, then $f^*$ admits a left adjoint $f_{\#}:\mathscr{M}(X) \longrightarrow \mathscr{M}(Y)$.

For algebraic-geometers, you can think of $\mathscr{M} = D^b_c(X,\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_l)$, $f^*,f_*$ the usual operators, $f_{\#} = f_!(-d)[-2d]$ ($(-1)$ Tate twist). Then you can see that there are several exchange structures associated to some class of cartesian squares
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
Y @>{q}>> X \\
@V{g}VV @V{f}VV\\
T @>{p}>> U
\end{CD}

- The exchange structure $\operatorname{Ex}^*_*: p^*f_* \longrightarrow g_*g^*p^*f_* = g_*q^*f^*f_* \longrightarrow g_*q^*$.
- Similarly, the exchange structure $\operatorname{Ex}_{\#}^*: q_{\#}g^* \longrightarrow f^*p_{\#}$ in case $p,q$ smooth, and we suppose this one to be an isomorphism.
- The adjoint structure of $\operatorname{Ex}_{\#}^*$ is $\operatorname{Ex}_{\#*}: p_{\#}g_* \longrightarrow f_*q_{\#}$.

In Remark 1.1.16, *Triangulated Categories of Mixed Motives* (by Cisinski and Déglise), the authors claim that given squares as follows, then there is a compatibility among three exchange structures above (I am sorry that I cannot draw such a commutative diagram on MO)

### [image: Heading]

I'm not even sure the second diagram is correct because both square $\Gamma,\Gamma'$ are not cartesian, so one cannot even talk about $\mathrm{Ex}_{\#*}$ (being the inverse of $\mathrm{Ex}^*_{\#}$). Is this a mistake in the book or they are making an abuse of notation (by pretending $\Gamma,\Gamma'$ are cartesian without inserting more notations of morphisms).

Comment: That is a mistake: we should only have made this remark under the additional assumptions that both $\Gamma$ and $\Gamma'$ are cartesian.

Comment: @Cisinski, That's still confusing, because if we keep the same notation, then of course $\Gamma,\Gamma'$ would never be cartesian, but if we change morphisms, for instance, $p,p'$ in $\Gamma$, we do not have a morphism $f^*p_*p'_{\#} \to q_*g^*p'_{\#}$.

Comment: That is embarrassing but you are right: Remark 1.1.16 is nonsense. The best is simply to ignore it (I do not think it is used anywhere seriously).

Comment: @Cisinski, I think you have to use it in Lemma 2.4.23.

Comment: We use the exchange isomorphism from 1.1.15 but 1.1.16 can be forgotten for ever for the reasons discussed above (and it is not used). We use some coherence properties, of course, but they are not justified by 1.1.16; they all follow from variations on coherence of the form discussed in 1.1.7 (or in a dual form).

Comment: No, not really, the proof of Lemma 2.4.23 uses three operations, in 1.1.7, only two are involved. We still need some variation of 1.1.16.

Comment: I consider the proof of Lemma 2.4.23 fine as it is. However, if you think some argument is missing, please tell me where exactly in the proof so that I can provide more details. However, 1.1.16 should not be used because it is plain nonsense...

Comment: If you want useful coherence properties, paragraph 2.2.9 as well as its followers (Prop. 2.2.10, 2.2.11 and Cor. 2.2.12) are meaningful: they summarize all the coherence you need between operations of the form $p_!$ against those of the form $f^*$ or $f_*$ and we do not need anything else in the proof of 2.4.23 or of any other result in the book (if you search the term 1.1.16 in the pdf file, you will see that we never quote remark 1.1.16 in any proof and that is because we use coherence from other parts of the book, such as 2.2.9).

Comment: @Cisinski, thanks, I think I need a verification for the commutativity of the lemma at the end of page 64.

Comment: Thank you for spoting this mistake. Any comment to improve the text or to ask for clarification is welcome.

Comment: You're welcome, I hope that you could provide some verification for the commutativity of the lemma at the end of page 64.

Comment: Well, it seems that the vertical maps of this diagram are in the wrong directions. I can provide more details on the commutaivity of the diagram, but that will be painful to write it here. If you reach me by email, I can send you a pdf file with more details, if you want.

Comment: @D.-C.Cisinski I alreay reached you one-two weeks ago if you remember